# iOS 11 UISearchController in Navigation Bar with UIRefreshControl causes layout glitch

Tags: uitableview, uikit, ios11, uisearchcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to use `UIRefreshControl` on a  table view together with the new `searchController` API on `navigationItem`.
Now when I set `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` the "pull down to refresh" animation is not showing anymore and the refresh control just pops in at a certain point.

[image]

It appears to be a bug in UIKit (...same procedure as every year). 
Did anyone find a solution for this one?

To reproduce the issue add this to a fresh iOS 11 "master/detail" sample project:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // [setup code here]

    self.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    self.navigationItem.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO; // <-- setting this causes jumpy UI
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I just experienced the same problem. It definitely looks like a bug in UIKit. It would definitely be something [filing a radar](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) would be worth.

I found a very hacky way to mitigate it though:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //Fixes a bug in UIKit where the refresh control is broken when `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` is NO.
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y < -scrollView.adjustedContentInset.top;
    }
}
```

Basically what's happening here is that whenever the scroll view scrolls past the top (where the refresh control would become visible), this bit of code will turn `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` back to `YES`. Once the user scrolls back down again, it will be set back to `NO` and the search bar will continue to remain visible.

Hopefully Apple will fix this in a future iOS version, but for current shipping versions, this will probably have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Table View's top constraint to the Superview, not SafeArea.

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```